# Method decorator that allows to execute a decorated method only once Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a task to Implement a method decorator that allows to execute a decorated method only once.
For example:

```
   class Test {
        data: any;
        @once
        setData(newData: any) {
            this.newData = newData;
        }
    }
    const test = new Test();
    test.setData([1,2,3]);
    console.log(test.data); // [1,2,3]
    test.setData('new string');
    console.log(test.data); // [1,2,3]
```

I tried a lot of combinations to make a function that being called twice do nothing,but it's not what i should have and unit tests are failing,so,this is what i have till now:

```
const once = (
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) => {
    const method = descriptor.value;
    
    descriptor.value = function (...args){
        // ???
    }
};
```

Unit tests:

```
describe('once', () => {
    it('should call method once with single argument', () => {
        class Test {
            data: string;
            @once
            setData(newData: string) {
                this.data = newData;
            }
        }
        const test = new Test();
        test.setData('first string');
        test.setData('second string');
        assert.strictEqual(test.data, 'first string')
    });

    it('should call method once with multiple arguments', () => {
        class Test {
            user: {name: string, age: number};
            @once
            setUser(name: string, age: number) {
                this.user = {name, age};
            }
        }
        const test = new Test();
        test.setUser('John',22);
        test.setUser('Bill',34);
        assert.deepStrictEqual(test.user, {name: 'John', age: 22})
    });

    it('should return always return first execution result', () => {
        class Test {
            @once
            sayHello(name: string) {
                return `Hello ${name}!`;
            }
        }
        const test = new Test();
        test.sayHello('John');
        test.sayHello('Mark');
        assert.strictEqual(test.sayHello('new name'), 'Hello John!')
    })
});
```

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excellent question - I ran into the same issue a week or 2 ago, and played with it a big before giving up.  I didn't need that feature so frequently, so I manually implemented this concept: declare a property on the class `this._setData = false`.  Inside `setData`, only run the code `if (!this._setData)`, and at the end of the running the code, do a `this._setData = true`.  This means the code will only run once.  As far as generalizing this to a decorator to apply to any method (instead of having to manually declare `this._value` every time), I'd like to know too!

Comment: Yes,i think i could do this approach,but the problem is that  *setData* function is only as an example,i dont know which functions could be called later or something like that.As you can see in unit tests,there is setData function,below is setUser,and the decorator should have the same behavior everywhere,but i dont know how to do this  :(

Comment: In `setData` you probably meant `this.data = newData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reflect-metadata` is pretty handy for this scenario. You could try something like this:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';

const metadataKey = Symbol('initialized');

export function once(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
    const method = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function(...args) {
        const initialized = Reflect.getMetadata(metadataKey, target, propertyKey);

        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }

        Reflect.defineMetadata(metadataKey, true, target, propertyKey);

        method.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

You can find some more information on it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata

Comment: This seems to work.  [Here is a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/once-decorator-reflect-metadata-uh62d?file=/src/index.ts) with an example.

Comment: One thing I notice is that this does not work when trying to decorate a get method.  I get an error `Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute`.  [Here's a codesandbox demonstrating that error](https://codesandbox.io/s/once-decorator-reflect-metadata-get-wuxh0?file=/src/index.ts).  Do you think its possible to expand / adjust this for provide the same functionality for `get` class methods?

Comment: @SethLutske I think to decorate a getter we'd need a property decorator. The question asked for a method decorator, so I think the current version is more suitable.

Comment: Would you mind writing out a property decorator in the answer as well?  Or if you prefer, I can ask that in a separate question?

Comment: @SethLutske Sorry, I misspoke. You're asking for an accessor decorator. Examples can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators.

Comment: @SethLutske Is [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/once-decorator-reflect-metadata-get-forked-d1zr5) the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241001/discussion-between-seth-lutske-and-plumbn).

Comment: For the curious, a question and answer for class get methods can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684052/accessor-decorator-that-only-runs-decorated-code-once-in-typescript-returns-pre)

Comment: Hey,your solution works for me,but it gives an error to the third test unit. :   ` <failure message="Expected values to be strictly equal:
[32m+ actual[39m [31m- expected[39m

[32m+[39m undefined
[31m-[39m &apos;Hello John!&apos;" type="AssertionError"><![CDATA[AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:
[32m+ actual[39m [31m- expected[39m ` It gives undefined for the third test,idk why..

Comment: @Pandos Maybe I misunderstood your desired result. The decorator in my answer will allow the method to execute once, but not again. I thought the objective was to prevent any subsequent execution after the first time the method is called. Your third test seems to expect different behavior.

Comment: @plumbn,there is no problem,i modified a little your solution and got the desired result.I thought i should have only this behavior too,but when i saw the test failing i saw that its not enough :D

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```js
const once = (
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) => {
  const method = descriptor.value;
  let isFirstTime = true;

  descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
    if (!isFirstTime) { return; }
    isFirstTime = false;
    method(...args);
  }
};
```

Comment: Won't `isFirstTime` get recreated and set to true every time the method is called though?

Comment: @SethLutske decorators are executed only once, when the class is declared. When the method is called, that method is actually the new function that had been assigned into `descriptor.value`. It does not re-run the decorator.

Comment: This seems to give me an error in [this example](https://tsplay.dev/mpvexw).  Try running the code, then uncomment the use of `@once`, and run it again.  There seems to be an issue accessing `this.property` properties from within the once method...?  If it were to work properly, the code should run, and print the `Cell` with a count of 1, even though the method is called 100 times

Comment: [This sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/once-decorator-4ogyl?file=/src/index.ts) gives a bit more information than the sandbox, with a ts compile-type error: `Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.ts(1241)`.  It has the same runtime error as the tsplayground in my previous comment

Comment: Looks to me like @ghybs is right. I think the answer here is just running into errors due to syntax or scoping issues. [This fork of the earlier sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/once-decorator-forked-pq4ke?file=/src/index.ts) appears to resolve the issues. The decorator and method only run once. Comment out the early return in the decorator and decorator is still executed only once while method is run 1000 times.

Comment: @SethLutske Besides the issue with `this` and `return`, actually the flaw in this answer is the reverse of your initial concern: there will be only ONE `isFirstTime` for the class, not one per instance. That is why we usually use a "hidden" instance member, or reflect-metadata like in plumbn's answer.

Comment: @ghybs, interesting.  I had experimented with something similar to this but was unsuccessful.  This particular answer doesn't seem to work, as shown by my ts playground and codesandbox examples.  I think the hidden instance members is the most readable, but requires a lot of repeated logic.  I like plumbn's answer, but it doesn't address the issue of getters, or when you want to calculate a value only the first time, and then simply return that value every other time without having to calculate it again.  I may write up a separate question to cover that case.

Comment: I tried your solution and i get the following error "Cannot set property &apos;data&apos; of undefined" type="TypeError"><![CDATA[TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined
    at Test.setData (test\index.ts:20:27)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar problem in this way:

```
function once(_target: any, _methodName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    let isFirstTime = true;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            isFirstTime = false;
            this.previousValue = originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        } else {
            return this.previousValue;
        }
    };
    return descriptor;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).