# Decorator to allow executing a method only once

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to create a decorator to prohibit executing the same method twice. This is what I've tried:

```
import functools

def only_once(func):
    func._called = False

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if func._called:
            raise RuntimeError("This function can only be called once.")
        func._called = True
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class A:
    @only_once
    def func(self):
        print("Called")
```

The problem:

```
a = A()
a.func()
    
b = A()
b.func()  # raises
```

It turns out that the state is shared across all the instances of the class, which is unwanted. I suppose this is because at the time my decorator's code is executed, the method is unbound, so it "belongs" to the class. Please explain why exactly this fails and also propose a way to fix it.

Comment: A solution would be store the flag in the class instance (aka `self`), rather than as an attribute on the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method decorator that allows to execute a decorated method only once Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671420/method-decorator-that-allows-to-execute-a-decorated-method-only-once-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Iarsks, I will store the state in the `self` which the method  belongs to:

```
import functools

def only_once(func):
    attr_name = "_called_funcs"

    def called_funcs_of_instance(instance) -> set:
        called_funcs = getattr(instance, attr_name, set())
        if not called_funcs:
            setattr(instance, attr_name, called_funcs)
        return called_funcs

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        called_funcs = called_funcs_of_instance(self)
        if func in called_funcs:
            raise RuntimeError("This function can only be called once.")
        called_funcs.add(func)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class A:
    @only_once
    def func(self):
        print("Called")
```

### Async support

```
def only_once(func):
    attr_name = "_called_funcs"

    def called_funcs_of_instance(instance) -> set:
        called_funcs = getattr(instance, attr_name, set())
        if not called_funcs:
            setattr(instance, attr_name, called_funcs)
        return called_funcs

    def logic(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]
        called_funcs = called_funcs_of_instance(self)
        if func in called_funcs:
            raise RuntimeError("This function can only be called once.")
        called_funcs.add(func)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logic(*args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    @wraps(func)
    async def async_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logic(*args, **kwargs)
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)

    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
        return async_wrapper
    else:
        return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

The method object (a descriptor) is always shared between all instances of a class. As a demonstration:

```
class A:
    def say_hello(self, who):
        print (f"Hello {who}")

a = A()
another_a = A()
```

Now we can check that 'a' and 'another_a' are different objects:

```
>>> id(a) == id(another_a)
False
```

But the descriptor is common to both:

```
>>> id(a.say_hello) == id(another_a.say_hello)
True
```

So as you've correctly surmised, your _called attribute is being set on the class, not on the object instance.

One solution would be to use a class decorator, with an instance variable holding a set of (instance, function) tuples to record what has already been called.

For example:

```
import functools
import weakref
import types

class once_only:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.called = set()
        self._func=func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _self = args[0]
        instance_func = (weakref.ref(_self), weakref.ref(self._func))
        if instance_func in self.called:
            raise RuntimeError("This function can only be called once.")
        self.called.add(instance_func)
        return self._func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):           
       return types.MethodType(self, instance)

class A:
       @once_only
       def say_hello(self, who):
           print (f"Hello {who}")

a = A()
another_a = A()

a.say_hello('MMM')
another_a.say_hello('Stackoverflow')
a.say_hello('MMM')
```

Note the use of weak references here to avoid the decorator preventing instances from being garbage collected.